# Unsure why 'continue' is necessary within this if statement

Tags: python

I am wondering why `continue` is necessary in the following code

```
t = df[price_column]
ts = 0
idx = []
for i, x in enumerate(tqdm(t)):
    ts += 1
    if ts >= m:
        idx.append(i)
        ts = 0
        continue
    return idx
```

I know that `continue` returns control back to the beginning of the loop, but I don't see why anything would change if it wasn't there.

Comment: What happens if you removed it? Do you still get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

`continue` causes the rest of the loop body to be skipped, so it's being used to skip the `return` statement. This isn't a very clear way of achieving that though. A much cleaner way of writing this would be to just use an `else`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(tqdm(t)):
    ts += 1
    if ts >= m:
        idx.append(i)
        ts = 0
    else:
        return idx
```